# ServiceNow Templating - "Share this ticket with other users"

Tags: templates, servicenow

Does anyone know if it is possible to add "Notes" in the template? Specifically want to "Share this Ticket with other users" for every ticket we create.

example image below:
[Share this ticket with other users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Evvl8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like notes is a section and Share this ticket with other users is a list type field in it. By default, it should be present in every new ticket that you create. Unless the requirement is something different than what it seems.